# FFMPEG fade in/out expressed in milliseconds

Tags: ffmpeg, fadein, fadeout, milliseconds

I working on a programmatic sketch to cut, crop and fade in/out audio from a single input video file.
Everything works pretty well except for the audio fade in fade out.

Everything work fine if I set a fade in and fade out time of 1 (or more) seconds. Here's my command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:1:11.10 -i INPUT_FILE.mp4 -filter:a afade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0,afade=t=out:st=55.867:d=1.0 -filter:v crop=720:720:138:0 -to 0:0:56.86 OUTPUT_FILE.mp4
```

Fade filter stop working if I set time less than 1 secs (say 100ms like the following example).

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:1:11.10 -i INPUT_FILE.mp4 -filter:a afade=t=in:st=0:d=0.1,afade=t=out:st=56.767:d=0.1 -filter:v crop=720:720:138:0 -to 0:0:56.86 OUTPUT_FILE.mov
```

I mean, ffmpeg is not complaining about any error but the output video file simply has no fade in or fade out.

Why?
What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your support

**Edit 22/07/2020**:
here's the output from the second command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:1:11.10 -i 2020-07-20_00-13-35.mkv -filter:a afade=t=in:st=0:d=0.1,afade=t=out:st=56.767:d=0.1 -filter:v crop=720:720:138:0 -to 0:0:56.86 ./_selections/2020-07-20_00-13-35_R1_crop2_w_fadein_fadeout_0:1:11.10.mov
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '2020-07-20_00-13-35.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:03:19.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2661 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1440x900, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:19.233000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : audio desktop
      DURATION        : 00:03:19.065000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to './_selections/2020-07-20_00-13-35_R1_crop2_w_fadein_fadeout_0:1:11.10.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:19.233000000
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : audio desktop
      DURATION        : 00:03:19.065000000
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
frame= 1706 fps=140 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2685kB time=00:00:56.86 bitrate= 386.7kbits/s speed=4.67x    
video:1681kB audio:942kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.351145%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] frame I:7     Avg QP:15.76  size: 60653
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] frame P:448   Avg QP:23.13  size:  1372
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] frame B:1251  Avg QP:31.17  size:   545
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  2.3%  1.4% 95.0%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] mb I  I16..4: 29.2% 37.7% 33.1%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.4%  0.5%  P16..4:  2.1%  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.4%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.3%  0.2%  B16..8:  1.5%  0.1%  0.1%  direct: 0.0%  skip:97.8%  L0:51.7% L1:46.3% BI: 2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] 8x8 transform intra:43.2% inter:27.7%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.4% 42.2% 40.1% inter: 0.3% 0.5% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] i16 v,h,dc,p: 61% 37%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30%  7% 59%  2%  0%  0%  0%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 17% 25% 10%  4%  5%  5%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] i8c dc,h,v,p: 66% 19%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] ref P L0: 65.1% 15.3% 13.6%  5.9%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] ref B L0: 68.1% 27.1%  4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] ref B L1: 95.3%  4.7%
[libx264 @ 0x564dad2f9680] kb/s:242.09
[aac @ 0x564dad2f25a0] Qavg: 606.451
```

Comment: Show the complete log from command 2. Audio fading works for me in simple example: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=d=10 -filter_complex "afade=t=in:st=0:d=0.1,afade=t=out:st=9.9:d=0.1,showwavespic" out.png`

Comment: hi @llogan, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @llogan I've edited my original post!

Comment: Running your command on a sine and loading the result into Audacity shows a fade in and a fade out.

Comment: Thank you @llogan, don't know why, if I do the same on a video file and load its audio track on a DAW, I don't see any fade. I see only when I set a much longer fade time...

Comment: This time I tried your same command on the same ffmpeg version on a MKV with sine audio of same duration and it again showed the fading in Audacity (and it can be heard upon playback). Perhaps your DAW does not have granular enough representation of the waveform. I am unable to make ffmpeg not work, so I am not convinced it is the problem.

Comment: Thank you @llogan, I think I will give it a try with another DAW (I've always used Reaper). I suspect the problem will remain from the moment that playing the output video and, say, putting it in loop mode inside VLV, I'm not able to hear any fade. I'll let you know. Thank you for your support.